# Why does clearing and rewriting this tkinter frame make it duplicate?

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I'm working on an RPG-style game using the `tkinter` module in Python and I have a character creation screen with randomly-generated stats. The 6 stats are generated by using the `random` module.

The problem that I'm having is when I clear the screen to repack the numbers into the frame dedicated to them it works the first time, the numbers clear and a new set of numbers appears, however the second and third time (and so on) I press the button it just generates a new set of numbers inside the frame whilst the previous numbers remain, duplicating the amount of numbers.

I've tried running various different methods seen from this site such as `.pack_forget` and deleting from the screen, I even set the variables used to store the Labels to `None` but nothing I try seems to work.

I'll post the code below, the program is several hundred lines so forgive me if I missed anything related to the problem.

```
def CharManage2Option3Command(StrengthValue, DexterityValue, ConstitutionValue, WisdomValue, IntelligenceValue, CharismaValue, statframebottomleftright, statframebottomrightright):
    StrengthValue.destroy()
    DexterityValue.destroy()
    ConstitutionValue.destroy()
    WisdomValue.destroy()
    IntelligenceValue.destroy()
    CharismaValue.destroy()
    StrNumber = randrange(3, 18)
    DexNumber = randrange(3, 18)
    ConNumber = randrange(3, 18)
    WisNumber = randrange(3, 18)
    IntNumber = randrange(3, 18)
    ChaNumber = randrange(3, 18)
    StrengthValue = Label(statframebottomleftright, text=StrNumber, fg=DefaultColour, bg=WhiteBackgroundColour, font=DefaultFont)
    DexterityValue = Label(statframebottomleftright, text=DexNumber, fg=DefaultColour, bg=WhiteBackgroundColour, font=DefaultFont)
    ConstitutionValue = Label(statframebottomleftright, text=ConNumber, fg=DefaultColour, bg=WhiteBackgroundColour, font=DefaultFont)
    WisdomValue = Label(statframebottomrightright, text=WisNumber, fg=DefaultColour, bg=WhiteBackgroundColour, font=DefaultFont)
    IntelligenceValue = Label(statframebottomrightright, text=IntNumber, fg=DefaultColour, bg=WhiteBackgroundColour, font=DefaultFont)
    CharismaValue = Label(statframebottomrightright, text=ChaNumber, fg=DefaultColour, bg=WhiteBackgroundColour, font=DefaultFont)
    StrengthValue.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    DexterityValue.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ConstitutionValue.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    WisdomValue.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    IntelligenceValue.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    CharismaValue.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: I may have missed something here, but why is it necessary to recreate the different labels each time the value changes? You can call `.config(text="New Text")` on the variable holding the label object and just change the text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the assignment e.g. `StrengthValue = Label(...)` inside the function *does not* affect the object that was passed in, it just assigns a new object to that name *inside the function*. Therefore the first time you call the function the original objects are `destroy`ed as expected, but you don't retain a reference to the new objects (as they aren't `return`ed from the function) so subsequent calls appear to behave incorrectly.

One solution is to pass mutable arguments, e.g. lists containing the relevant objects:

```
def CharManage2Option3Command(label_lists, stat_frames):
    for label_list, stat_frame in zip(label_lists, stat_frames):
        for index, label in enumerate(label_list):
            number = randrange(3, 18)
            label.destroy()
            label_list[index] = Label(stat_frame, text=number, ...)
            label_list[index].pack(...)
```

*(see the docs on [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).)*. This would then be called e.g.:

```
CharManage2Option3Command([[StrengthValue, DexterityValue, ConstitutionValue], 
                           [WisdomValue, IntelligenceValue, CharismaValue]],
                          [statframebottomleftright, statframebottomrightright]):
```

Note this has the handy side-effect of reducing duplication in your function. You could also keep the `Label` instances in a list from the start, rather than keeping a separate reference to each one.

---

Other solutions include explicitly `return`ing the new labels from the function and assigning back to the original names:

```
def CharManage2Option3Command(StrengthValue, DexterityValue, ConstitutionValue, WisdomValue, IntelligenceValue, CharismaValue, statframebottomleftright, statframebottomrightright):
    ...
    return StrengthValue, DexterityValue, ConstitutionValue, WisdomValue, IntelligenceValue, CharismaValue
```

then calling it:

```
StrengthValue, DexterityValue, ConstitutionValue, WisdomValue, IntelligenceValue, CharismaValue = CharManage2Option3Command(StrengthValue, DexterityValue, ConstitutionValue, WisdomValue, IntelligenceValue, CharismaValue, statframebottomleftright, statframebottomrightright)
```

(which is obviously pretty awkward), using an `IntVar` as the `textvariable` for the `Label` and updating that or doing something class-based, such that you access e.g. `self.StrengthValue` everywhere.

---

I also suggest you have a look at the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which provides conventions for things like function and variable names.

Comment: Thanks so much, got this working with my code on your first method.